# YADCF datatable column filter - filtering rows based on values in hidden field in column

Tags: datatables-1.10, yadcf

I am using **Data table 1.10** and have a requirement to filter individual column some of the column having textbox with some values.

I want to filter that column by textbox value is it possible in 
"**Yet another Data table Column Filter **" ?

This functionality available in Data table 1.10

I need same functionality in **"Yet another Data table Column Filter"** plugin.

Please see my attempt:

```js
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html'] = function ( sData ) {
    return $(sData).val();
}

var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$("#search").on('keyup', function() {
    table.columns(2).search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

```css
#search {
    width: 30px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col #1</th>
            <th>col #2</th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search"/></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td><td>text</td><td><i class='fa fa-arrows'></i><input type='hidden' value='0'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>more content</td><td>more text</td><td><i class='fa fa-bar-chart'></i><input type='hidden' value='1'/></td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td>content #2</td><td>text #2</td><td><i class='fa fa-user'></i><input type='hidden' value='2'/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xdhgn55q/  is example with data table  1.10

Comment: Please include the code as part of your question and not within an external site.

Comment: Added JSFiddle as a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [your fiddle after modification](http://jsfiddle.net/xdhgn55q/23/) (also included yadcf css/js)

You better use [datatables html5 data attributes](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) and tell yadcf to html5 data by specifying the [html5_data](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L94)

So your js code will look like this:.

var table = $('#example').DataTable();

```
yadcf.init(table, [{
    column_number: 2,
    filter_type: 'text',
    html5_data: 'data-search'
}]);
```

and the relevant `td` will look like this

`<td data-search="1"><i class='fa fa-bar-chart'></i>
      <input type='hidden' value='1' />
 </td>`